# With a - and +, I am to the left

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

With a - and +, I am to the left.

With a switch, I am a name.

With 2 I have fixed.

With a -, I am 0.

With 0, I run.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> NILE

General reasoning

> The "-" and "+" indicate subtracting and adding letters, respectively, "switch" indicates swapping two letters and "with 2" indicates adding two letters, all to form new words.

With a - and +, I am to the left.

> NILE - E + P = [NILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Labour_Party), a centre-left party from Northern Ireland.

With a switch, I am a name.

> NI**EL**, as in [Adolphe Niel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolphe_Niel)

With 2 I have fixed.

> NILE + {A,D} = N**A**ILE**D**

With a -, I am 0.

> NILE - E = NIL

With 0, I run.

> The NILE is a river which *runs* through several countries in North-Eastern Africa.

Comment: Apart from the first clue you 'nailed' the rest of them congratulations... can you work it out?

Comment: What gave it away?

Comment: Was it the second to last clue?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 The second to last and last clues were what I focused in on, yes. I will think about the first line again, was struggling to find a good fit. Nice puzzle

Comment: Thanks, have you had a look at my other puzzle?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Yes, but I've not figured it out.